# How to show that you can make a power set of a finite set from the singletons of that finite set?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

The question is as follows:
Let $\Omega$ be a finite or countable set. Show that if $\mathcal{F}$ is an event space of subsets of $\Omega$, such that $\{\omega\} \in \mathcal{F}$ for all $\omega \in \Omega$, i.e. the event space $\mathcal{F}$ contains all singletons, then $\mathcal{F} = \mathcal{P(\mathcal{\Omega})}$.

I understand that, by showing that one can make all the subsets from the singletons, one can prove the above. How does one make this proof though?

Comment: A $\sigma$-algebra is by definition closed under countable unions.

Comment: @Karl What do you mean by this. What is a $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: @Alex If your definition of event space is different from the standard one ('it's a $\sigma$-algebra') then you should say what it is.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I have never come across the term $\sigma$-algebra before. What does it mean?

Comment: @Alex https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_space#Definition https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A3-algebra

Answer (score 0):

$\mathcal{F}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$, which includes all its singletons by assumption. Since $\mathcal{F}$ is stable under (countable) unions, you can reconstruct every subset of $\Omega$ by unions of the said singletons. Finally, since $\mathcal{F}$ contains all the subsets of $\Omega$, you can conclude that $\mathcal{F} = \mathcal{P}(\Omega)$.